# Error with iCal/ics feed

Tags: php, calendar, icalendar

I am trying to create a feed of events from my website but getting an error in iCal when I try to import. I would like it to be a feed user's subscribe to to have events automatically added to iCal or Outlook.

I am sending these headers:

```
Content-Type: text/Calendar
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=ical.ics
```

And here is the contents of the file being generated. Right now it only has a single event but eventually it will have multiple BEGIN:VEVENT.

```
TZ: America/New_York
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:Calendar Feed
PRODID:-//Herkimer//iCal 5.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20120801T141628Z
DESCRIPTION:
DTEND:20120926T220000Z
DTSTAMP:20120926T220000Z
DTSTART:20120926T220000Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20120801T141628Z
LOCATION:Building
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:Test Event
TRANSP:OPAQUE
UID:5577
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-ALLOWEXTERNCHECK:TRUE
X-MS-OLK-AUTOFILLLOCATION:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Do you know why it is erroring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first line is not valid,

> TZ: America/New_York

you can also further validate with:[this online ical validator](http://icalvalid.cloudapp.net)

Comment: Great validator, really helped!